# Inventory short coding

Tags: swift

So I've got a question.
I am making a game, with an Inventory system.
Since I am new to programming I search a lot on the internet and make it as easy as possible, but writing easy code is a lot of text..

So about the inventory, I got 15 buttons named:

```
@IBOutlet var invbtn1 : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var invbtn2 : UIButton!
... til 15
```

they get an image of a "dropped item"
the variables of that "dropped item"
going to my inventory class

```
class inventory1 {
var x = int()
var Y = int()
}
class inventory2 {
var x = int()
var y = int()
} 
... til inventory15
```

So my question is, is there a way to make this shorter? And if so, how?

Comment: The easier way is to create buttons programmatically using some basic config like JSON where you can store amount of buttons needed for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the buttons, you should dynamically generate them in `viewDidLoad`. For the inventory slots, you should put them in an array.

In the `viewDidLoad`, you want to create a `UIButton` in a for loop and add it to the main view.

```
var inventoryBtns: [UIButton] = []
override viewDidLoad() {
    for i in 0..<15 {
        var btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(i * 30 + 5, 10, 30, 30))
        // the above creates a button. Its size is 30x30 and the x coordinate of it is i * 30 + 5
        //here you can set the image and other properties of btn, omitted
        inventoryBtns.append(btn)
        view.addSubView(btn)
    }
}
```

Now you can access the first button using

```
inventoryBtns[0]
```

And the second using

```
inventoryBtns[1]
```

The third using

```
inventoryBtns[2]
```

And so on.

Now for the inventory, I don't understand why you create so many classes. But from the look of your code, you created 15 classes that contains the same thing. I think you should create a tuple array for this

```
var inventory: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = [()]
```

You access the first item of the inventory like this:

```
inventory[0]
```

And the second like this

```
inventory[1]
```

And so on.

If you want to access the`x` of the first item you can

```
inventory[0].x
```

That's pretty easy isn't it?

If you understand little of the above, I strongly suggest you to read *The Swift Programming Language 2.0* by Apple Inc. because that's how I learnt swift!

Seriously, if you want to build an inventory system and you lack basic knowledge of tuples and arrays, just go get some basic stuff! Don't think that you can build a whole inventory system with just a tiny bit of knowledge of swift.

Also, if you are building a game, use SpriteKit, not UIKit.

EDIT:

If you want to add an action to the button, you first need to create a function

```
func btnPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
     //implement the action here
}
```

And now in the for loop, add this before the `append` thingy

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: "btnPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

As you can see, for the the `action` parameter you just need to pass the method name with a colon `:` at the end.

Comment: Thanks that kinda makes all sence :) but i like to put my buttons on my screen so i do not have to put coordinates for evry singe button. About the var inventory. They do need the same tings so ill chexk that out when i'm home from work :) and the about that book, my mate buyed it so whe lends it put when he is trying some new stuff but i rather search the internet for more accurate answers on what i actualy need :)

Comment: @Kristof.V if you insist on putting the buttons on the storyboard, then you can't shorten the button part. I mean, that's your choice. I guess you will come to a similar situation in the future, so no harm learning how to do it now.

Comment: i might look into the button part aswel, would be lot easyer. But to make a function  for the button do you still need to make for evry button a different action?

Comment: And its a UIKit becous atm its our first try with just clicking and no animations :)

Comment: @Kristof.V if the buttons do roughly the same thing, you can just create one action function for all of them, see the code in my answer.

Comment: I've been trying what you did but

var inventory: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = [()]
Gives an error..
If i put it like this
var inventory: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = []
it doesen't give an Error but if i do
inventory[0].x = 10
and print it to my label, it gives an Error when i press the button